# File hiding virus for USB

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, virus

Every time i connect any USB flash drive the files become hidden 
i know how to view the files but i cant get that damn virus from my PC
i believe that this a virus so i installed Avira 2014 and Malware bytes but nothing could detect it

anyone can tell me a software that can remove it or tell me how to remove it manually ?

PS: I'm not asking for a way to view the files i want to remove the virus completely

I'm using win 7 ultimate 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[Kaspersky Rescue Disk 10](http://support.kaspersky.com/4162)".

It's specialized linux. And it is designed to scan, disinfect and restore infected operating systems (Windows). It also should be used when it is impossible to boot the operating system.

All, what you need is [download](http://rescuedisk.kaspersky-labs.com/rescuedisk/updatable/kav_rescue_10.iso), record it to a CD / DVD or any USB device and then start your computer from it.

Also Kaspersky provides a free-of-charge software, easy way to find viruses and other threats that may be hidden on your PC: [look here](http://www.kaspersky.com/virus-scanner).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a Windows config issue...
http://www.howtogeek.com/97203/how-to-hide-a-drive-in-windows-so-that-no-one-will-know-its-there/

If it is virus it is called Autorun
google youtube Autorun, there are a lot of videos show you what to do about it